# Eclipse FTP sync with local files - whats the easiest way?

Tags: eclipse, ftp, synchronization, local-files

i got trouble setting up eclipse to work with files on my FTP server. For example the RSE Plugin doesnt work good with Java 7 (there is a bugreport about it) so i had to switch back to Java6 and still, Eclipse crashes constantly because i hit ctrl+s (save) all the time. And it kinda freezes to upload the file. Which is very, very unconnvenient.

What i want now is a solution that stores all the data locally on my machine and have it synced with the FTP-Server.
I saw Plugins like Aptana but apparently there are a lot of warnings about it too.
I'd like just an easy way to define the FTP-Server and the local path where the project should be stored and that's it. Sadly i couldn't find a tutorial on anything that's as easy as that.

**Basically i need an eclipse plugin that replaces programs like [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/index.html).**

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, may be try as an alternative http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

Comment: i accepted your answer as it is the best i could get. Not EXACTLY what i want, but good enough and there havent been any other suggestions, sadly. Thanks again for the link!